# How to add manually updated userdata script to terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I added a new userdata script manually when there was an outage. I wanted to add this script back to terraform so that terraform state is up-to-date.

I'm not sure what is wrong here, its trying to recreate the instance.

What's wrong with my terraform changes?

Manually added user_data script in ec2 instance:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0
--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"
#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
iptables -F
echo "UserData is Executed"
--//
```

Existing config:

cloud-init.tpl

```
#cloud-config
---
package_update: true
packages:
  - docker

#This runs on every boot
bootcmd:
  - sh -c "sudo service docker start"

#These do not run on every boot
runcmd:
  - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - sh -c "sudo service docker start"
  - mkdir /data
  - ${format_command}
  - echo "/dev/xvdf /data ext4 defaults,noatime 0 2" >> /etc/fstab
  - mount -a

#ihr-deployer key
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa 
AAxxxx
```

data.tf

```
data "template_file" "cloud_init" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/cloud-init.tpl")}"

  vars = {
    format_command = "${local.new_volume == 1 ? "sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf" : "echo DEVICE HAS ALREADY BEEN FORMATTED"}"
  }
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "cloud_init" {
  part {
    content = "${data.template_file.cloud_init.rendered}"
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
  user_data                   = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.cloud_init.rendered}"
```

Changes:

```
data "template_cloudinit_config" "cloud_init" {
  part {
    content = "${data.template_file.cloud_init.rendered}"
  }

  part {
    filename     = "userdata.txt"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = "iptables -F\necho \"UserData is Executed\"\n"
  }
}
```

Output:

user_data:                             "c3b472b9b74264b21237dd7e71f0ff89d76b83b2" => "231c0e27943da00a4c0df284bf194729020ed105" (forces new resource)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to ignore user_data changes:

```
resource "aws_instance" "blah" {
  ...
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["user_data"]
  }
}
```